# How can I loop a certain part of my code for a game?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to loop a part of my code for a quick and short battle game.

I've tried out some while true statements but I'm not sure I understand it too well.

```
    print("A: Attack")
    time.sleep(.2)

    print("B: Skill")
    time.sleep(.2)

    print("C: Defend")
    time.sleep(.2)

    print("D: Rest")
    time.sleep(.2)

    turn1 = input("Input: ")



    if turn1.lower() == "a" or turn1.lower() == "b" or turn1.lower() == "c" or turn1.lower() == "d":
      if turn1.lower() == "a":
        damaget1 = random.randint(1,5)
        print("You did " + str(damaget1) + " damage!")
        enemyHealth -= damaget1
        print("AI is now at " + str(enemyHealth) + " health.")

        damaget2 = random.randint(1,5)
        print("The bot did" + damaget2 + " damage!")
        healthValue -= damaget2
        print("You are now at " + healthValue + " health!")
```

After that last part is when I'd like it to loop up to the top part. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code with an option to exit the program early as well

```
import time
import random

enemyHealth = 100
healthValue = 100

while enemyHealth > 0 or healthValue> 0:
    print("A: Attack")
    time.sleep(.2)

    print("B: Skill")
    time.sleep(.2)

    print("C: Defend")
    time.sleep(.2)

    print("D: Rest")
    time.sleep(.2)

    print("E: Exit")
    time.sleep(.2)

    turn1 = input("Input: ")



    if turn1.lower() == "a" or turn1.lower() == "b" or turn1.lower() == "c" or turn1.lower() == "d":
      if turn1.lower() == "a":
        damaget1 = random.randint(1,5)
        print("You did " + str(damaget1) + " damage!")
        enemyHealth -= damaget1
        print("AI is now at " + str(enemyHealth) + " health.")

        damaget2 = random.randint(1,5)
        print("The bot did" + str(damaget2) + " damage!")
        healthValue -= damaget2
        print("You are now at " + str(healthValue) + " health!")

    if turn1.lower() == "e":
        break




print("Game Over")
```

Comment: It worked, with a little bit of changes to my code. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  Please feel free to check the answered checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

just put this inside a while loop and set condition for exit.

```
while enemyHealth > 0 or healthValue> 0
    print("A: Attack")
    time.sleep(.2)

    print("B: Skill")
    time.sleep(.2)

    print("C: Defend")
    time.sleep(.2)

    print("D: Rest")
    time.sleep(.2)

    turn1 = input("Input: ")



    if turn1.lower() == "a" or turn1.lower() == "b" or turn1.lower() == "c" or 
turn1.lower() == "d":
      if turn1.lower() == "a":
        damaget1 = random.randint(1,5)
        print("You did " + str(damaget1) + " damage!")
        enemyHealth -= damaget1
        print("AI is now at " + str(enemyHealth) + " health.")

        damaget2 = random.randint(1,5)
        print("The bot did" + damaget2 + " damage!")
        healthValue -= damaget2
        print("You are now at " + healthValue + " health!")
print("Game Over")
```